# Visual C++ syntax error for pointer reference initialization

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Why does Visual C++ 2008 give a syntax error for the following code?

```
int* x;
int*& xalias(x); //error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'x'
```

Is this simply a bug? (gcc and clang accept this...)

Do later versions of Visual Studio fix this, or should I just work around this as below?

```
int*& xalias = x;
```

Comment: Doesn't work in VS2012 either. Looks like a bug. `int*& xalias = x;` works, of course.

Comment: If you have a Microsoft connect account, you can file a bug report at https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/Feedback. BTW, I can repro the issue in VS2010. Language spec which describes reference initialization syntax [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference_initialization).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your workaround is fine, and yes it is a bug in Microsoft's C++ compiler.  Here is the [bug report](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/540356/visual-c-unable-to-initialize-a-reference-to-a-pointer-with-parentheses-syntex) submitted to Microsoft.  They don't appear in a hurry to fix it as there is a trivial work around, as you found yourself.